# C# Named string parameters with Dictionary<string,string> as source?

Tags: c#, regex, string, dictionary, format

I'd like pass named parameters to a String.Format -like function, in the form of a Dictionary. For example:

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    { "Pi", "3.14"},
    { "Foo", "Bars"},
    { "Bird", "Pelican"}};

var myString = "This {Bird} weighs {Pi} {Foo}".NamedFormat(parameters);\

// Now myString = "This Pelican weighs 3.14 Bars";
```

It must also handle escaped curly brackets correctly:

```
"{{ don't change this}} {{{ButChangeThis}}}" --> "{ don't change this } {Some value}"
```

There seems a popular summary of options here:

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/01/04/fun-with-named-formats-string-parsing-and-edge-cases.aspx/

However I find each example lacking in either handling of escaped brackets, or, support for an IDictionary<> in addition to anonymous objects. (Those using DataBinder.Eval can't be easily modified to accept IDictionary<> instead of object)

Any other ideas?

Comment: Ideas of what kind are you looking for? Clearly not other links as it would be offtopic, there is no code you posted that demonstrates problem (you show use case, but no implementation you seem to have issues with), or maybe something else?

Comment: I guess you may use Replace method for replacing special marked substrings with it's value by your dictionary

Comment: It seems, that the easuest way is to implement a finite automate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this *finite automata* parser:

```
  public static class StringFormatExtensions {
    public static String NamedFormat(this String value, IDictionary<String, String> data) {
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        return value;

      StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder();
      StringBuilder Key = new StringBuilder();

      Boolean inBraces = false;
      Boolean SkipClose = false;

      foreach (Char Ch in value) {
        if (inBraces) {
          if (Ch == '{') {
            if (Key.Length <= 0) {
              inBraces = false;
              Sb.Append('{');
            }
            else
              Key.Append(Ch);
          }
          else if (Ch == '}') {
            inBraces = false;

            String item;

            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, data))
              throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
            else if (!data.TryGetValue(Key.ToString(), out item))
              throw new FormatException("Key {" + Key.ToString() + "} not found");
            else if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, item))
              Sb.Append(item.ToString());

            Key.Clear();
          }
          else
            Key.Append(Ch);
        }
        else if (Ch == '{') {
          inBraces = true;
          SkipClose = true;
        }
        else if (Ch == '}')
          if (!SkipClose) {
            Sb.Append(Ch);
            SkipClose = true;
          }
          else
            SkipClose = false;
        else {
          Sb.Append(Ch);
          SkipClose = false;
        }
      }

      if (inBraces)
        throw new FormatException("Unclosed } in the string.");

      return Sb.ToString();
    }
  }
```